# Confused about using 'useState' in two separate functions

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In order to get data from my AWS Postgres DB, I have to first get an AWS Access Token and pass it into the GET call.  To accomplish this, in my React app, I've created a file called `requests.js` into which I plan to build a number of functions.  Here are the first two:

```
// Custom hook to get AWS Auth Token
export const useGetAwsAuthToken = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async function() {
      try {
        const config = {
          headers: { "Authorization":  
            await Auth.currentSession()
            .then(data => {
              return data.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
            })
            .catch(error => {
            })
          }
        };
        setData(config);
      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      } finally {
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return { data };
};

// Custom hook for performing GET requests
export const useFetch = (url, initialValue) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialValue);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async function() {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        if (response.status === 200) {
          setData(response.data);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [url]);

  return { loading, data };
};
```

I was under the impression that I could use `const [data, setData] = useState();` in both of these functions and that they would be independent of each other.  However, back where I call the functions, my IDE is telling me that "data has already been declared" with the 2nd call:

```
  const {data} = useGetAwsAuthToken();
  const {loading, data} = useFetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
```

Furthermore, say I comment out the 2nd line of code above and make this call:

```
const {data2} = useGetAwsAuthToken();
```

This leaves `data2` as undefined.  This is also confusing because shouldn't I be able to have any named return value variable in the calling function?

Answer (score 0):

First, the one that is easier to answer for me: `const {data2} = useGetAwsAuthToken` isn't valid because you're using destructuring and it's expecting the value of data. So what you're telling it is the equivalent of saying `const data2 = useGetAwsAuthToken().data2` What you actually want is `const { data: data2 } = useGetAwsAuthToken()`. This will take the value that is returned (`data`) and save it to the current scope as `data2`.

Now for the first issue you brought up. Why are you using react life cycles in what appears to just be a function? You don't need to save things in state when it's just a function that's not returning a React Component.

Comment: Thank you for your insight!  Your first paragraph makes complete sense.

As for my overall approach, I thought that I had to use `useEffect` when dealing with any "side effects" with React functional components?

In my situation, I would absolutely like to store the AWS Access token inside of a React Context API property.  I will try doing this without using `useEffect`.

Comment: This of `useEffect` more as a 'When this component renders, what do I want to do immediately following that?'